# PHP - retrieve lowest and highest values from elements groups

Tags: php, xml, loops

Can't find a proper way to do the following: i have xml which contains elements where each one has a attribute order and the value ranging from 0-3. They are ordered by that attribute (0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3...) and are siblings. A number of the elements can vary and it's not necessary that the first one in the document starts with 0 as the XML is refreshed every 4 hours and with every refresh the current first element get's deleted and the next element in line take's over the first position. For example: at 0:00 am the first element has attribute order="0". At 6:00 it gets removed and the next sibling takes he's (first) place with attribute order="1".

I would like to do a loop for a group of elements where they are ordered from 0-3 (except the first group where the first element may have order 0, 1, 2, or 3) and retrieve lowest and highest values of each group child nodes. For example:

```
Lopping the bottom structure should print:

11, 82
2, 92
1, 211
...

<parent>

    <!-- Group 1 -->
    <element order="2">
        <node value="30" />
        <node value="82" /> <!-- This is the highest of the Group 1 -->
        <node value="25" />
    </element>
    <element order="3">
        <node value="12" />
        <node value="52" />
        <node value="11" /> <!-- This is the lowest of the Group 1 -->
    </element>

    <!-- Group 2 -->
    <element order="0">
        <node value="21" />
        <node value="78" />
        <node value="33" />
    </element>
    <element order="1">
        <node value="35" />
        <node value="57" />
        <node value="88" />
    </element>
    <element order="2">
        <node value="22" />
        <node value="92" /> <!-- This is the highest of the Group 2 -->
        <node value="81" /> 
        <node value="19" />
    </element>
    <element order="3">
        <node value="2" /> <!-- This is the lowest of the Group 2 -->
        <node value="30" />
        <node value="44" />
    </element>

    <!-- Group 3 -->
    <element order="0">
        <node value="12" />
        <node value="99" />
        <node value="43" />
    </element>
    <element order="1">
        <node value="65" />
        <node value="211" /> <!-- This is the highest of the Group 3 -->
        <node value="16" />
    </element>
    <element order="2">
        <node value="32" />
        <node value="55" />
        <node value="77" /> 
        <node value="1" /> <!-- This is the lowest of the Group 3 -->
    </element>
    <element order="3">
        <node value="68" />
        <node value="74" />
        <node value="21" />
    </element>
    <!-- Group 4 -->
    ...

</parent>
```

Hope the question is not to widely asked. The comments are not included in the XML.

Comment: What have you tried so far, please?

Comment: Nothing actually :/ I've tried with foreach but stuck to retrieve the min/max values from each group. I'm guessing i should create an array for each of the while looping and put the values inside corresponding array.

Comment: As the XML get's updated (based on time of the day) the order changes. For example: at 0:00 am it has order="0", but at 6:00 am it get's removed so the next node becomes first (order="1").

Comment: When you for each are you within the individual nodes (the groups)? If so, just create a variable immediately outside THAT loop and compare the current value against that. If it's greater or null set it to current value. Same principle for lowest.

Comment: Hm, could you give an example?

Comment: Your XML is invalid... how can you have an opening `<element>` with a closing `</foo>` ?

Comment: Ah OK I think I see the challenge. Don't have time for comprehensive look atm but if no one's answered in about an hour I'll take a shot at it.

Comment: Thanks @Mikey, edited.

Comment: @Sundance.101 thanks :)

Comment: Is there a `<group>` level you're not showing, or does the code literally need to inspect *inside* XML comments to determine which elements are part of which group?

Comment: Nope, the elements are not nested and the comments are also not included in the xml - i should probably mention that.

Comment: @g5wx Just taken a better look at this and don't think I can add to  Darien and Mikey's input. 
If you don't have them in order or have some additional node within which to nest your groups, you can't programmatically determine where the groups begin and end. Sorry, dumped into vs code, but there's no point looking at it further unless you can control the data to at least that level.

Comment: Yes, i guess so to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way.

This solution will only work if the attributes are ordered e.g. `1, 3, 4` and not e.g. `3, 0, 4`.

```
$string = <<<XML
<!-- XML data goes here -->
XML;

// suppress some errors
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

// step 1: group all the values

// keep track of the previous order to determine when we have a new group
// INF is just an arbitrarily large number to start the first group
$prevOrder = INF; 
$groups = [];
$i = -1;

foreach ($xml->element as $element) {
    $order = (int) $element->attributes()['order'];
    // start a new group if the current order is smaller than the previous order
    if ($order <= $prevOrder) {
        $groups[++$i] = [];
    }
    // store the next values in that group
    foreach ($element->node as $node) {
        $groups[$i][] = (int) $node->attributes()['value'];
    }
    $prevOrder = $order;
}

// step 2: get the minimum and maximum of each group

foreach ($groups as $group) {
    printf('%d, %d<br>', min($group), max($group));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mikey, although i need to find a way to create the first "group" regardless of what the starting number is, i will see if i can use your solution and modify it - upvoted.

Comment: The first group will always be created regardless of the starting number. The important thing is that the orders must be strictly increasing for each group.

Comment: I've created another question where the xml has a date stamp. If you could take a look if it's easier this way i would appreciate it a lot, thanks.